# Issue with updating - max_file_uploads

Tags: php, iis-7

Hey guys I have a website hosted under winhost.  I have a php function that will upload a whole csv file.  It will need to be able to upload thousands of entrys and in order for that to work they told me to change the `max_file_uploads` and `max_execution_time`.  They told me I could do this with creating a user.ini file, which I did and put the following code into it:

```
max_file_uploads = 1000
max_execution_time = 1200
```

This worked except it did not change the file_uploads,  It only changed the execution_time.  I made sure by checking in my phpinfo section.  They also said to try to switch the PHP...FastCGI with PHP5 by using IIS - switching the order list.  I did this but no success, it removed my max_file_uploads and changed would not let me adjust my execution_time.

So recap:  I cannot update the `max_file_uploads`, I can only update the `max_execution_time`.

Comment: Try `ini_set("max_file_uploads", 1000);` on the top of your code.

Comment: Inside the user.ini file?

Comment: No that did not work at all.

Comment: Have you tried changing php.ini ?

Comment: Don't have access to that

Comment: Ok, seems that this is a security measure against DOS attacks ... You may try create an .htaccess in the same folder as the PHP file(s) and add this line `php_value max_file_uploads 1000`. If it doesn't work, you may search for a JS/jQuery solution ...